# Mock same method with different return value

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest.mock

I want to patch `get_age()` method I have, based on the argument passed.

Let's say I have `get_age.py` where I am using multiple times the same `get_age()` method.

```
get_age("Anna")
...
get_age("Ben")
```

and then in test I want to do:

```
@patch('get_ages.get_age') <-- mock getting age of Ben
@patch('get_ages.get_age') <-- mock getting age of Anna
def test_get_ages(self, age_A, age_B):
```

How can I do the mocking of the same method based on the name passed? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `side_effect` param to `patch.object` to call a function which returns a different result depending on the input.  For example:

```
def find_ages(*args):
    if args[0] == 'Anna':
        # Return Anna's data
        return 18
    elif args[0] == ' Ben':
        # Return Ben's data
        return 45

@patch.object(get_ages, 'get_age', side_effect=find_ages)
def test_get_ages(self, get_age):
```